# Lucene.Net include hyphen in tokenizer

Tags: c#, .net, lucene

In Lucene, I wish to index products - and as I understand it, words such as t-shirt get tokenized into "t" and "shirt".

I wish that searches for "shirt" don't match t-shirt - i.e. - treat "t-shirt" as a single token.

What's the simplest way to achieve this?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could update the rules for the `StandardTokenizer` and create a custom one.

To do this regenerate the [StandardTokenizerImpl](http://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/3.0.3/db/d77/_standard_tokenizer_impl_8cs_source.html) class using [JFlex](http://www.jflex.de/) by altering the original rules. (You would need to translate the output to c#)

Then take the code for the [StandardTokenizer](http://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/3.0.3/dc/db6/_standard_tokenizer_8cs_source.html) and alter it to use the newly generated TokenizerImpl from JSFlex.

If you don't need the existing rules in the StandardTokenizer you could also try using the [WhiteSpaceTokenizer](http://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/3.0.3/db/d4a/class_lucene_1_1_net_1_1_analysis_1_1_whitespace_tokenizer.html).

Comment: Thanks - I ended up just using a WhiteSpaceTokenizer, as you suggested - with some extra filters baked-in